# HTML input always return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, scope

```js
let form = document.getElementById("info");
var angle = Number(form.angle.value);
alert(angle);
var power = 0.01;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var dc  = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mgnt = canvas.getContext("2d");
//then angle anf power values goes into another function
```

```html
<form id="info">
   Power:<br>
  <input type="number" name="power" id="power"><br>
   Angle:<br>
  <input type="number" name="angle" id="angle"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

My problem is whatever i give input alert give me 0. If I give angle input with decleration (var angle = 30;) rather than html input everything works fine. What is the problem

Thank you guys, I fixed it :)

Comment: The form is initially empty when the page loads, and the script executes immediately, so it alerts 0 because that's the numeric representation of the empty string value of the angle field.

Comment: move the code to an `oninput` callback for the form input. then you also get to use `this.value` instead of in-event dom methods

Comment: If you'd like to see the values of Power and Angle when the user click 'Submit', you have to implement one function then bind it to 'Click' event of 'Submit' button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **dynamically** **get** a value on change or `"submit"` Event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```js
let form = document.getElementById("info");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {

  // Don't submit form! (Remove this line later - so you can submit! ;))
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var angle = Number(form.angle.value);
  alert( angle )

});
```

```html
Enter an angle and hit SUBMIT

<form id="info">
  Power:<br>
  <input type="number" name="power" id="power"><br> 
  Angle:<br>
  <input type="number" name="angle" id="angle" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Your JS is syncronous in the means that executes immediately (when possible) top to bottom. There's no assigner nor entered value at that time. On `submit`, instead, you can go chech that element value! Or also on that `<input>`'s `"input"` Event:

```js
const angle = document.getElementById("angle");

angle.addEventListener("input", function () {
  
  const val = Number( this.value );
  console.log( val );
  // do someting smart with #angle's val

});
```

```html
Enter an angle and watch it happen ;)

<form id="info">
  Power:<br>
  <input type="number" name="power" id="power"><br> 
  Angle:<br>
  <input type="number" name="angle" id="angle" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you are trying to get form values immediately.

Get form values after form submit.

```
form.onSubmit = function() {
  var angle = Number(form.angle.value);
  // rest of the logic
}
```